# Audio con Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy usando la función playsound() del módulo con el mismo nombre, porque estoy aprendiendo audio con python, y resulta que me dio curiosidad de hacer un piano con Tkinter y playsound. Puse un botón cuyo comando es ejecutar playsound("do3.mp3"), y al presionar el botón varias veces, lo único que logro es tener que esperar a que el sonido se reproduzca todas esas veces. He probado multithreading para poder hacer sonar el audio varias veces al mismo tiempo y no funciona, porque el botón no hace nada como si no tuviera comando asignado:

```
from playsound import playsound
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import threading

piano_30 = "Assets/30.mp3"

window = Tk()

def play_30():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=("piano_30"))

button_30 = Button(window, command=play_30)
button_30.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta iniciar la tarea con el comando `thread.start()`. Teniendo en cuenta esto, tu función debería de ser asi:

```
def play_30():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=("piano_30",))
    thread.start()
```

**Nota Adicional**:
para que Python interprete `(valor)` como tupla, es necesario agregar una coma antes de cerrar parentesis de este modo: `(valor,)`.
La diferencia entre `(valor)` y `(valor,)` es que uno es equivalente a `valor` y el otro es una tupla que contiene a `valor`.

Comment: Gracias, soy muy descuidado. Me respondiste a tiempo porque estaba haciendo un piano como ejercicio con Tkinter y Playsound. Las notas sonaban como un segundo luego del click con Multiprocessing. Ahora lo cambié a Multithread y suenan instantáneamente.